# how can i convert a timestamp to Regular Expression

Tags: regex, regular-language

I want to convert my log timestamp into Regular Expression, how can I convert this timestamp to Regular Expression format?

Fri Dec 21 19:09:36 +0000 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this below format

> > EEE M dd HH:mm:ss Z Y